# Retrieving value from Table/Record

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, user-defined-types

I created a custom record type say `record_object` which has a value `column3`. This record is populated as

```
OPEN cur_record FOR query;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_record BULK COLLECT INTO record_object;
    FOR i IN 1..record_object.count;
    END LOOP;
    EXIT WHEN cur_record%notfound;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I want to compare `record_object(i).column3` with a value in `Table1`. This table isn't that huge so i was thinking to create something

```
TYPE RTable1 IS RECORD
(
  column1 varchar2(10),
  column2 varchar2(10)
);

Type TTable1 IS TABLE OF RTable1 INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
record_table1 TTable1;
```

This record will be fetched via a query as well. Now the question is that I want to compare `record_object(i).column3` with `record_table1.column2`. I don't want to use 2 nested loops. Is there a way like something hashtable that i can implement on `Table1` that when i ask to see if `record_object(i).column3` exist in it, it returns that specific row / index ?

P.S:
Please ignore my syntax errors, I write my sql while posting it here.

Comment: Why are you doing this in PL/SQL rather than SQL?  Obviously "compare"  can mean any number of operations, but a JOIN would likely be way faster than whatever you have in mind here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your queries to return ordered set of strings. Comparision of two ordered arrays would be easy and fast.